# gopro hero vs gopro hero4 black video quality diference

Tags: video, quality, gopro

I want to buy gopro camera,
I see there is big diference in price e.g.

http://www.gopro.hr/kamere/p/GoPro-Hero/ProductID/9426
cost $200

http://www.gopro.hr/kamere/p/GoPro-Hero4-Black/ProductID/19131
cost $600

big diference in cost, what is diference in quality of video, photo and options ?

Comment: Have you looked on the official GoPro website? All the specs and comparison data you could wish for is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are charts on their website, but in short, the Black allows for 4k recording, 60 mbps bandwidth, higher frame rates at various resolutions, simply put, it has a larger bottleneck enabling it to capture more data.

I would suspect the cameras may be perhaps identical, and are firmware locked down into lower levels for the less expensive versions. Bypassing that would be, well very difficult if not impossible.

The Blacks are great, I own a handful and use them all the time.